# powershell - Replace only old files with new files in destination directory

Tags: powershell, replace, directory, copy-item

[image]

Hello All,

I wish to replace only the old file with new file

I tried

```
Set-Location C:\contains_newfolder_contents\Old Folder
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { 
  if ((Test-Path 'C:\contains_newfolder_contents\Sample Folder\$_' ) -and
    (.$_.LastWriteTime -gt C:\contains_newfolder_contents\Sample Folder\$_.LastWriteTime' )) {
      Copy-Item .\$_ -destination 'C:\contains_newfolder_contents\Sample Folder' 
  }
}
```

Kindly correct me!

Comment: what did not work as expected?

Comment: Did you try robocopy? It's made for.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-line solution.  I used different folder names to make the example easier to read.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp\destination|foreach-object {$sourceItem = (get-item "c:\temp\source\$($_.name)" -erroraction ignore); if ($sourceItem -and $sourceItem.LastWriteTime -gt $_.lastwritetime) {Copy-Item -path $sourceItem -dest $_.fullname -verbose}}
```

For each existing file, it finds the matching file in the source folder.  $sourcItem will be null if there is no matching source item.  It proceeds to compare the dates and copy if the source date is newer.

Comment: -Can you make this copy if the destination also does not exist, with the same line? That's what I think is needed here; Look to see what is there and copy only new "lastwritetime" or new.....                                                                                        **Get-ChildItem f:\ |foreach-object {$destinationItem = (get-item "d:\batch\$($_.name)" -erroraction ignore); if ($destinationItem -ine $_) {Copy-Item -path $destinationItem -dest $_.fullname -verbose}}**

Comment: Yes, basically, invert the logic so that it starts by getting all source items and then looks up the matching destination item.  Then if the destination item exists, do the date comparison, and copy or not depending on that result.   If it doesn't exist, just copy source to dest.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it too :

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\contains_newfolder_contents\Old Folder" -file | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | select -First 1 | Copy-Item -Destination 'C:\contains_newfolder_contents\Sample Folder'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making several reads to the source, I propose you make a lookup table and then these simple commands will achieve the desired results.

```
$source       = 'C:\temp\Source'
$destintation = 'C:\temp\Destination'

$lookup = Get-ChildItem $destintation -Recurse | Group-Object -Property FullName -AsHashTable

Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse |
    Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -gt $lookup[$_.FullName.Replace($source,$destination)].lastwritetime} |
        Copy-Item -Destination $destintation
```